# Why stripe is throwing the error after unmounting the card element?

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments, stripes

After unmounting the card element, the below error occurs

> **v3/:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element.
> Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.
> at Oe (v3/:1:85179)
> at e._handleMessage (v3/:1:90713)
> at e._handleMessage (v3/:1:102981)
> at v3/:1:88616**

Below is the js code.

test.js file

```
$('#edit_cc_details').on('click', function(){
        var stripe = Stripe($('#frmAdditionalCards').data('stripe-publishable-key'));
        var elements = stripe.elements();
        cardElement = elements.create('card');
        cardElement.mount('#new_credit_card');

        var form = document.getElementById('frmAdditionalCards');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // console.log(card);
            stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the user if there was an error.
                    alert(result.error.message);
                } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                }
            });
        });

        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            var form = document.getElementById('frmAdditionalCards');
            var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
            form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

            // Submit the form
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('#cancel_cc_details').on('click', function(){
        if (cardElement) {
            cardElement.unmount();
        }
    });
```

I tried adding the below line, it removes the mounted card element. But after submitting the form it throws the error.

`cardElement.unmount();`

[image]
[image]

Comment: So the error message tells you you need to make sure it **is still mounted** - and you are trying to achieve that via `cardElement.unmount();` ...? That doesn't sound like it would make any sense.

Comment: Maybe try putting up a minimal example on JSFiddle etc with instructions on how to replicate the problem you're facing.

Comment: @CBroe you are not getting my flow, the flow is like if the user click on edit button for updating the credit card details and if user mind changes and he don't want to update and click on the cancel button so the card that was mounted needs to be unmounted else it will throw validation error so i have wrote the "cardElement.unmount" inside the cancel button event. The div where I am mounting the card elements are getting empty but at the time of submitting the form it throws the given error

Hope so u are getting the point.

Comment: So _when_ does this error actually occur? When `#frmAdditionalCards` gets submitted?

Comment: @CBroe once the card is mounted then it get unmounted by clicking on the cancel button so the <div id="new_credit_card"></div> becomes blank but there is a save button in the form and after clicking on it the forms get submitted and that time it throws the error I pasted. The card is getting unmounted but the error is not letting me submit it

Comment: When your edit button gets clicked, you add a submit handler to the form - a submit handler, that doesn't get removed again anywhere. And in that submit handler, you do `stripe.createToken(cardElement)` - with a `cardElement`, that you have already unmounted at this point, if the cancel button was clicked.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks a lot for solution error resolved.